# Google Chrome autosaves css changes on the inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

When I make changes on the css inspector it also apply the changes to the css on the sources panel. So I right-click and save the source panel css to a file.
The problem is that once I make this for the first time, google chrome is now autosaving any modification I make on the css inspector.

Is there some way to disable this autosave feature?

Comment: I've been searching for this too, but it seems to not be possible. Shame, because it causes me a lot of problems committing changes that I didn't intend to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think so (it's very handy afterall). Once you save it the first time, it will auto-refresh until you close that locally saved version. However you can use "Local Modifications..." (right-click CSS in sources) and revert History.